# Is there a way to get kafka streams and camel metrics in telegraf using micrometer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-streams, telegraf, micrometer

I have Kafka streams and camel in my application and I want to fetch some metrics from it and send it to influx via telegraf. For all the other metrics in my application we are using micrometer. Is there a way to fetch camel routes metrics and kafka stream metrics using micrometer?

Comment: Take a look at the camel-micrometer component and its route policy factory: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-micrometer/src/main/docs/micrometer-component.adoc#micrometerroutepolicyfactory and there is also an example with Camel at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-micrometer

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Camel metrics there is [the Micrometer component which lives in the Apache Camel repo](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-micrometer) but at the time of writing there is no out-of-the-box support for Kafka Streams metrics yet although there is [a Micrometer issue for the Kafka which targets for 1.1.0-rc.1](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/512).